# What was the concept behind the communication in the episode Such Great Patience?

Tags: seaquest

What was the concept behind the communication between...

> ...the hologram and Darwin? There was one scene where they couldn't understand the transmission from the alien space ship but then mentioned something about Dolphins using a different frequency and then they could then translate it into Dolphin sounds? Is what they are talking about the equivalent to slowing down or speeding up the playback of a sound?

Also, in relation to the above question they said that dolphins were the most intelligent species on the planet a million years ago. If man came on the scene a hundred thousand years ago. Is that accurate? (as far as we know obviously)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as the "alien signal" is concerned, the [writers](http://home.comcast.net/~kimurho/sq/1-20-68934.html) seem to be at odds with themselves, initially describing it as a high frequency sound;

> **Tim O’Neill:** *I’m at a loss to explain it, Captain.  Sensors show a sound out there, but I    can’t find it; high frequency, well out of
>   our **acoustical** parameters.*
>
> **Nathan Bridger:** *Is this something he could hear?*
>
> **Tim O’Neill:** *Technically it’s out of his range too.*

But then later suggesting that it's actually a radio signal composed of microwaves;

> **Tim O’Neill:** *Lucas and I have isolated the alien signal.  An overlapping pulse on a high microwave frequency...*

Either way, the idea that a dolphin (whose sound perception and hearing range is somewhere between [75 Hz and 150 kHz](http://www.sarkanniemi.fi/akatemiat/dolphin_senses.html)) can either hear microwaves or hear sounds that aren't perceptible by a modern [hydrophones](http://www.teledyne-reson.com/products/hydrophones/) (which have a range between 15hz and over 500Khz) makes little or no sense.

Occasionally you have to put up your hands and say "this makes no sense!". This is one of those times... :-)

---

Nathan Bridger's description of humans a million years ago not being "anything more than glorified apes" or less intelligent than dolphins is almost wholly inaccurate. Protohumans like Homo Heidelbergensis possessed a complex verbal and gestural communication style and a tool-making ability that would put contemporary dolphins to shame.

Then again, Seaquest is set in an alternative reality where dolphins are able to speak directly (albeit via a translator) so it's decidedly possible that in that reality, dolphins *were* the more intelligent species.

[image]